# CKEditor plugin for ASP.NET, 'ExtraPlugins' property doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, plugins, ckeditor

I have two ASP.NET Web Forms Apps, first targeted to v4.0, second to v4.5 of .NET framework. I use ASP.NET CKeditor plugin v3.6.4. Everything work great, except that I can't register my 'phrases' plugin using 'ExtraPlugins" property.
Javascript solution works:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('<%=CKEditor1.ClientID%>',
        {
            extraPlugins: 'phrases',
            toolbar:
            [
                ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'],
                ['phrases']
            ]
        });
```

But 'ExtraPlugins' property solution doesn't work:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor" ExtraPlugins="phrases" Toolbar="Basic" runat="server" />
```

Please for help.

Best regards,
WP

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What should it do? What does it do? Do you get any errors in the developer console? What browser?

Comment: I have developed working and tested plugin named 'phrases'. In my Web App, If a register it using above Javascript code, plugin's icon appears in CKEditor toolbar and user is able to fire this plugin. On the other side, if I try to register plugin using ASP.NET `CKEditor:CKEditorControl` control's `ExtraPlugin` property, the plugin icon doesn't appear in CKEditor toolbar, thus user has no chance to fire it.

Comment: Not works in all top browsers, no errors in developer console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some experiments and finally I know how it works.

The following ASP.NET CKEditor Web Control tag is placed in *.aspx page:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor" ExtraPlugins="phrases" Toolbar="Basic" runat="server" />
```

Then, this tag is rendered in the outcoming HTML document and shipped to the user browser in that way:

First part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
CKEditor_TextBoxEncode('CKEditor1', 0); 
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Second part:

```
<textarea name="CKEditor1" rows="2" cols="20" id="CKEditor1">
</textarea>
```

Third part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var CKEditor_Controls=[],CKEditor_Init=[];function CKEditor_TextBoxEncode(d,e){var f;if(typeof CKEDITOR=='undefined'||typeof CKEDITOR.instances[d]=='undefined'){f=document.getElementById(d);if(f)f.value=f.value.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');}else{var g=CKEDITOR.instances[d];if(e&&(typeof Page_BlockSubmit=='undefined'||!Page_BlockSubmit)){g.destroy();f=document.getElementById(d);if(f)f.style.visibility='hidden';}else g.updateElement();}};(function(){if(typeof CKEDITOR!='undefined'){var d=document.getElementById('CKEditor1');if(d)d.style.visibility='hidden';}var e=function(){var f=CKEditor_Controls,g=CKEditor_Init,h=window.pageLoad,i=function(){for(var j=f.length;j--;){var k=document.getElementById(f[j]);if(k&&k.value&&(k.value.indexOf('<')==-1||k.value.indexOf('>')==-1))k.value=k.value.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>').replace(/&amp;/g,'&');}if(typeof CKEDITOR!='undefined')for(var j=0;j<g.length;j++)g[j].call(this);};window.pageLoad=function(j,k){if(k.get_isPartialLoad())setTimeout(i,0);if(h&&typeof h=='function')h.call(this,j,k);};if(typeof Page_ClientValidate=='function'&&typeof CKEDITOR!='undefined')Page_ClientValidate=CKEDITOR.tools.override(Page_ClientValidate,function(j){return function(){for(var k in CKEDITOR.instances){if(document.getElementById(k))CKEDITOR.instances[k].updateElement();}return j.apply(this,arguments);};});setTimeout(i,0);};if(typeof Sys!='undefined'&&typeof Sys.Application!='undefined')Sys.Application.add_load(e);if(window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener('load',e,false);else if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent('onload',e);})();CKEditor_Controls.push('CKEditor1');
CKEditor_Init.push(function(){if(typeof CKEDITOR.instances['CKEditor1']!='undefined' || !document.getElementById('CKEditor1')) return;CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor1',{"extraPlugins" : "phrases", "htmlEncodeOutput" : true, "toolbar" : "Basic"}); });
//]]>
</script>
```

In the third part of source code, there is the most important statement, which is rendered equivalent of ASP.NET CKEditor tag:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor1',{"extraPlugins" : "phrases", "htmlEncodeOutput" : true, "toolbar" : "Basic"}); });
```

As we can see, ASP.NET WebControl's property `ExtraPlugings` is linked with `extraPlugins` property in Javascript configuration of CKEditor instance.

After some recognitions it turns out that JS configuration `extraPlugins` option actually doesn't attach plugin to be visible in CKEditor toolbar and ready to use, but in fact only register the plugin to allow to use it. Plugin can be registered in that way, or in `config.js` configuration file of CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.extraPlugins = 'phrases';

    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
};
```

After registration, the plugin have to be somehow added to the toolbar to be available for use, for example in that manner:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor" ExtraPlugins="phrases" Toolbar="[{ name: 'plugins', items: ['phrases'] }]" runat="server" />
```

or by use of Javascript Code.

Thus, in summary: `ExtraPlugins` property only cause a registration of plugin. If we want to have it on CKEditor Toolbar, we have to write proper statements to configure CKEDitor toolbar.

Comment: Great info and thanks for adding an answer to your own question! I choose to use CKE without the asp.net control because I think it's much simpler to just write the needed HTML+JS myself directly but this clarifies how the control works a lot.